# How can I get the array of uint16 from the serialnumber property in wmimonitorinfo using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wmi, monitor

I want to get the `serialnumber` of my monitor with JavaScript, but without using the registry. I have tried it like this:

```
var objWMIService = SWBemlocator.ConnectServer(strComputer, "/root/wmi");
var colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorID");
var enumItems = new Enumerator(colItems);
var tmp;
for (; !enumItems.atEnd(); enumItems.moveNext())
{
    var objItem = enumItems.item();
    tmp = objItem.ManufacturerName;
}
alert(String.fromCharCode(tmp));
```

The alert shows just 'undefined' and if I try other `int` properties it runs normal.